# What is '-c' in the command ./vendor/bin/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml app/code/Vendor/Module/Test/Unit?

Tags: testing, phpunit

I just know I can execute my test file with this command through PHP-Unit framework but haven't figured out what '-c' is for.

Comment: https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.3/textui.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-c followed by path to file means that this is where phpunit can find the configuration file for the test